# Tasklist is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I have built an asp.net MVC application, which is working fine on IIS in the same machine where source project is laying. However I have to change some code in my source project but when I start my project in visual studio 2013, builds process runs and failed. It shows the following error.

> 1>  'tasklist' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> 1>  operable program or batch file.
>
> 1>  C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1131,5):
>   error MSB3073: The command "tasklist /fi "imagename eq iisexpress.exe"
>   |find ":" > nul
>
> 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1131,5):
>   error MSB3073: if errorlevel 1 taskkill /f /im "iisexpress.exe""
>   exited with code 255.

When I ran this command `taskkill /f /im iisexpress.exe` then no process is found message appear.

do you know what is causing this?

Answer (score 5):

depending on the version of windows you are currently running, taskkill is indeed not included.
If you believe that taskkill is included, it is possible that your path is set incorrectly.
I had the same issue on a jenkins that I do not manage myself.

My solution was to adapt the path in the local shell

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\System32;
```

however, this was for a .bat file.

For c# i have no solution handy, but maybe this can point you in the right direction.

Comment: taskkill exe will be available in system32 folder .. go to that folder and run the command

C:\Windows\system32​